# Need iOS alternative for this Android function. interpreter.runformultipleinputsoutputs (inputArray, outputmap)

Tags: android, swift, iphone, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am using Tensor flow to detect mobile phone devices.

Now model which I have used gives 4 Outputs so I used "interpreter.runformultipleinputsoutputs (inputArray, outputmap)" function in Android to get a single output result.

Its work properly in my Android devices but I am not able to find alternative function for iOS.

Can you please let me know which functions should I use to get same result in iOS also?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcKVb.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Swift implementation does not have / need a separate function for multiple inputs / outputs. As [example here shows](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference), after instantiating the `interpreter`, you call

```
// Allocate memory for the model's input `Tensor`s.
try interpreter.allocateTensors()
```

to allocate inputs and outputs, which can be multiple.
You then add those inputs as `Data` using

```
try interpreter.copy(inputIdsData, toInputAt: 0)
try interpreter.copy(inputMaskData, toInputAt: 1)
try interpreter.copy(segmentIdsData, toInputAt: 2)
```

where `toInputAt` is actually the index of the input (see [an example with multiple inputs](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/a228a3460f3fdd8edee9e8b061a08ffc92629907/lite/examples/bert_qa/ios/BertQACore/Models/ML/BertQAHandler.swift), where I took those lines from).
Similarly, the outputs are retrieved as `Data`

```
endLogitsTensor = try interpreter.output(at: 0)
startLogitsTensor = try interpreter.output(at: 1)
```

where `at` is the index of the output, 0 being the first.